# How to run updated python script in linux terminal

Tags: python, linux, terminal, run-script

I am missing something really obvious here... but when I run this program

```
python gregs_program.py
```

it will work fine....  but if I make changes and then save it, I go to run

python gregs_program.py

and it runs the old version (doesn't update my changes)!  I notice I have both

"gregs_program.py" and
"gregs_program.py~"  when I do the 'ls' command in Terminal.

What am I missing here?

Comment: write permissions ?  or maybe try copying it to another file and run it. `files with ~` are temporary or backup files.

Answer (score 4):

The problem could only be a few things (all of which I have done before):

- The editing window is not in the same place (directory/computer) as the run window.
- There was an error writing the updated copy, maybe from a readonly filesystem, out of space, etc.
- The editor is in some weird mode and did not receive a command to write.

Comment: @user3583384: we've all been there. To avoid keeping multiple copies of the source code, use a version control system such as `git`, `hg` (mercurial) for your experiments.